# Build libedgetpu on opensuse

Tags: bazel, opensuse, google-coral

I try to build libedgetpu von a `openSUSE LEap 15.2`. I've downloaded the sources and started **make CPU=k8 libedgetpu** and failed:

```
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24b4ccf868afbcf3a4d007a13f6e3a01/external/flatbuffers/src/BUILD:40:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@flatbuffers//src:flatc':
    this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/flatbuffers/src/util.cpp':
      '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/include-fixed/limits.h'
      '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/include-fixed/syslimits.h'
      '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/include/stdint.h'
      '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/include/stddef.h'
      '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/include/stdarg.h'
```

Any ideas why it failes? Bazel is completely new for me.

Comment: Hmm, seems that I have to add the system include path to the bazel config of libedgetpu. But how and where?

Comment: Grabbed deeper...the cxx_builtin_include_directories seems to be not correct. But how to set it for this project and all downloaded dependencies, especially crosstools?